# QueryOver error Could not execute query - Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, queryover

I tried to execute the QueryOver statement below on a SQL Server table and I catched an exception:

> "Could not execute query - Input string was not in a correct format"

the QueryOver statement:

```
IQueryOver<Customer> queryOver = this.session.QueryOver<Customer>();
IList<Customer> customerList = queryOver.List<Customer>();
```

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.CUSTOMER (
    CUST_CODE varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    CUST_NAME varchar(50) NULL
)
```

The class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public virtual long CustomerId { get; set; }
    [ColumnName("CUST_NAME")]
    public virtual string CustomerName{ get; set; }
}
```

the mapping:

```
public class CustomerMap : ClassMap<Customer>
{
    public CustomerMap()
    {
        Schema("DBO");
        Table("CUSTOMER");
        Id(c => c.CustomerId).GeneratedBy.Assigned().Column("CUST_CODE");
        Map(c => c.CustomerName).Nullable().Column("CUST_NAME");
    }
}
```

Can somebody tell me what's going wrong with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is C# property *(`long`)*

```
public virtual long CustomerId { get; set; }
```

mapped as **`long`** to column `"CUST_CODE"`

```
// type is deferred from type == long
Id(c => c.CustomerId).GeneratedBy.Assigned().Column("CUST_CODE");
```

but column  **`'CUST_CODE'`** is **`string`**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.CUSTOMER (
    CUST_CODE varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    ...
```

and that is the issue. Change one of these to match each other...

Comment: thanks for your response. although the column 'CUST_CODE' is string, I have to read it in the class as type == long.

Comment: The problem is that the table is a legacy databse that cannot be changed and the class was already designed it as it is.

Comment: How can I turn around thks problem ??

Comment: I can hardly tell you how to go with C# long and DB string... One of these should be changed. Any workaround will just postpone the moment, when such solution would explode. Adjust C# to have string ID would be the most simple, based on my experience

Comment: Thank you for your help. Im gonna verify the impact of the change.

Comment: You could rename your existing property to : `CustomerIdLong` and create a new property called `CustomerId` that did the conversion to a long for you.  You would have to create a getter and setter for this that set the underlying `CustomerIdLong` property which I would suggest you make protected so you don't have people trying to modify it directly. `CustomerId` would obviously not be mapped either. This is obviously a hack but...

Comment: Thank you for your sugestion.